# Enabling syntax hightlighting for Robot Framework in notepad++

Tags: notepad++, robotframework

I'm working on Robot Framework and I want the syntax highlighting feature of notepad++ for robot framework. I tried doing the below mentioned suggestions which I got from the Robot framework official website :

1) I tired downloading the xml file (lang-robot.xml) from GitHub(https://github.com/vkosuri/npp-robot) and importing it from notpad ++ but it didn't seem to work .

2) Then tried copying the lang-robot.xml file to the c:/program files(x86)/Notepad++ , even that didn't work .

Is there anyone who can help me out Please

Thanks in Advance

Comment: when you say it didn't seem to work, what happened?  What is the name of the file you're using to test it?

Comment: the name of the file is firstcode.robot  , i have made sure that it is . robot file

Comment: And after  i imported lang-robot.xml , i just got a pop stating "import successful"  but I was not able to see any difference in the code robot code i wrote ..there was no syntax highlighting done ..  And I even tried reopening notepad++

Comment: woops, added an answer by mistake, have you selected the language you added correctly as I mentioned?

Comment: I selected the language now and it is working perfect now !!!

Comment: can you accept the answer in that case?  Glad you got it sorted @novice

Comment: yes..I did :) Thanks for your time

Comment: you need to hit the green tick, currently I think you've only upvoted it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the file open in notepad, have you tried clicking on the 'Language' option and selecting the language you just added?  It will have whatever name you gave it when you were importing

Answer (score 1):

1.) Import the xml file (lang-robot.xml) from GitHub(https://github.com/vkosuri/npp-robot).

2.) Go to Notepad++ and define your Language options under Language settings in the toolbar.

3.) Import the xml file.

4.) Save the file as .robot file and try. ( without saving the file ,the highlighting doesnt work).